# How do I get an ID from a click event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an ID to use as a selector for a modal that I will then be able to access the display properties.

```
   $.ajax({
      url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=12',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        employees = data.results;
        $.each(employees, function (i, employee) { 

    newHTML += '<div id="' + i + '" class="container">';
    newHTML += '<div class="employee-img-container">';
    newHTML += '<img class="employee-img" src="' + employee.picture.large + '" alt="employee image">';
    newHTML += '</div>';
    newHTML += '<div class="employee-info-container">';
    newHTML += '<h3 class="employee-name">' + employee.name.first + ' ' + employee.name.last + '</h3>';
    newHTML += '<p class="employee-email">' + employee.email + '</p>';
    newHTML += '<p class="employee-location">' + employee.location.city + ', ' + employee.location.state + '</p>';
    newHTML += '</div></div></div></div>';

    employeeArr.push(employee);

    modalHTML += '<div id="modal' + i + '" class="modal">';
    modalHTML += '<div class="modal-content">';
    modalHTML += '<div class="modal-header">';
    modalHTML += '<span class="close">&times;</span>';
    modalHTML += '<img class="employee-img" src="' + employee.picture.large + '" alt="employee image">';
    modalHTML += '<h2 class= emp-modal-name>' + employee.name.first + ' ' + employee.name.last + '</h2>';
    modalHTML += '</div';
    modalHTML += '<div class="modal-body">';
    modalHTML += '<p>Employee Info</p>';
    modalHTML += '</div></div></div>';

    modalArr.push(employee);

    });
    $('.grid-container').html(newHTML);
    $('.modal-container').html(modalHTML);
        $('.container').on('click', function (event) {
            console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
            let newId = '#modal' + event.currentTarget.id;
            let displayModal = $(newId)
            let display = document.querySelector(newId);
            //displayModal.style.display = 'block';
            console.log(displayModal);
            console.log(display);
            console.log(newId);

});
}
});
```

When I log the `event.currentTarget.id` I get a number, and I can also create a string that I want to use as a selector. I can't figure out how to use it as the actual sector though. Not sure if I need to use an if statement to compare it to the id of the modal class that i want to display. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        alert(event.target.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what I'm trying to do is make a new id from the target id. Each instance of employee has an id of id=" + i . My modals have an id of id="modal + i. I want to be able to select the modal by ID by using the target to set number of the corresponding modal id. If i log newId I get the string that I'm looking for, but when I try to use it as a selector it returns null.